# What does this mean? DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname])

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, deprecation-warning

I've import a xlsx sheet into Python 3.6 by using import openpyxl and now am trying to access the Cell Object by doing the following (see below), but I immediately get an error message which I don't know what it means?:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
```

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:\\users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\example.xlsx')

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

Comment: The message seems pretty self-explanatory to me. The `get_sheet_by_name` is deprecated, which means it may be removed in a future version of `openpyxl`. The `DeprecationWarning` you see is telling you about that, and it tells you what to use instead.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than what you're doing, it's telling you to use a different format

```
 wb['Sheet1']
```

If you plan on using your script in the future, when that library is upgraded, it may break because you're using deprecated functions

Answer (score 1):

the right code :

import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:\users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\example.xlsx')

sheet = wb['Sheet1']

Answer (score 0):

If you don't anticipate to know beforehand what the sheetname is, then your code should be:

```
sheet = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
```

...which will automatically choose the left most sheet in the workbook

Furthermore, it is important to note that wb[0] produces a string object...

```
>>> wb.sheetnames[0]
'Sheet1'
```

and wb[wb.sheetnames[0]] produces a 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet' object...

```
>>> wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
<Worksheet "Sheet1">
>>> type(wb[wb.sheetnames[0]])
<class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet'>
```

This is important on how you plan to work with this object (e.g. iterating over your worksheet).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, hope it will help:

```py
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:\\users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
```